# Using conditions to return specific rows

Tags: sql, oracle

From the following table i am trying to retrieve specific rows based on a criteria

```
+----+--------------+------+
| ID | UPDATED_DATE | TYPE |
+----+--------------+------+
|  1 | 01/13        | P    |
|  1 | 02/13        | P    |
|  1 | 03/13        | P    |
|  2 | 01/14        | P    |
|  2 | 02/14        | W    |
|  2 | 03/14        | P    |
|  2 | 04/14        | W    |
|  2 | 05/14        | P    |
|  2 | 06/14        | P    |    
+----+--------------+------+

Expected rows:
+----+--------------+------+
| ID | UPDATED_DATE | TYPe |
+----+--------------+------+
|  1 | 01/13        | P    |
|  2 | 05/14        | P    |
+----+--------------+------+
```

Criteria:

> If type "W" exists in any of the rows for an ID then retrieve the next occurrence of 'P' after 'W'. If not retrieve the first occurrence of 'P'. If there are two 'W' for each ID then get the 'P' after the latest 'W'

I was successfully able to get the required row if i pass ID. But i want to run this for the entire table and get the necessary rows.

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN (
        SELECT
            MAX(UPDATED_DATE)
        FROM
            TABLE_NAME
        WHERE
            ID = '1'
            AND TYPE = 'W'
    ) IS NULL THEN
        (
            SELECT
                MIN(UPDATED_DATE)
            FROM
                TABLE_NAME
            WHERE
                ID = '1'
        )
    ELSE
        (
            SELECT
                MIN(UPDATED_DATE)
            FROM
                TABLE_NAME
            WHERE
                ID = '1'
                AND UPDATED_DATE > (
                    SELECT
                        MAX(UPDATED_DATE)
                    FROM
                        TABLE_NAME
                    WHERE
                        ID = '1'
                        AND TYPE = 'W'
                )
        )
END
FROM
   dual;
```

Comment: What is the order that defines "*next*" / "*prior*" in your table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
with wp as (
      select t.*,
             lag(id) over (partition by id order by updated_date) as prev_id,
             min(case when type = 'W' then id ) over (partition by id) as min_w_id,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by updated_date) as seqnum
      from t
      where type in ('W', 'P')
     )
select
from wp
where (min_w_id is null = 0 and seqnum = 1) or
      (prev_id = min_w_id);
```

Comment: This one works well. But if the there are multiple occurence of  'W' for each ID, then it is returning both of them. I need only one row per ID.

Comment: @GaneshChippada . . . That is not listed in your criteria.  I would suggest that you ask another question.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that criteria. However i edited the question.